# can't find anything about an operator I heard about in java

Tags: java, operators

so someone had mentioned to me about an operator like the "==" in java but they said instead it was "dot equals" or ".=" I am assuming... I have looked up documentation on all the java operators but can't find this one anywhere, even went to the official oracle documentation list of operators and searched for it and couldn't find it... is this really a thing in Java? if so what does it do?

Comment: There is the method `equals`, as in `x.equals(y)`. Maybe that's what you're looking for.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.htmlhttps://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Answer (score 0):

equals method is defined is Object class

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

```
o.equals(p)
```

Comment: ahhh ... yeah I know about .equals... silly ...  i thought they meant literally ".=" whoops...guess this was a pointless question and duplicate then

Comment: haha no you got it wrong then.. no problem they really meant .equals but read the concept behind using it.. it's really amazing

Comment: == -> is a reference comparison, i.e. both objects point to the same memory location... while .equals compare the value of both object

Answer (score 0):

They might have meant .equals() instead of '.=' since '.=' ain't a thing
The difference between == and .equals() is that objects can override .equals() to suit there purpose and == just checks it